# EACCES: permission denied error when trying to add file in docker volume

Tags: node.js, docker-compose, dockerfile, permission-denied, docker-volume

I try to write a file in the refunds volume but I get this error regarding access permission: `EACCES: permission denied, open '/var/lib/refunds/data/1665130080268-53ee4cf2-173b-4f3d-8350-33c02cd9f944.png'`
I created and added the volume's link in the docker-compose file.
Even when I enter the docker container and try to reach that volume's link I got permission denied.
How do I write in refunds-volume?

This is my dockerfile:

```
FROM node:lts-alpine3.16 AS builderdevices
RUN apk add --no-cache python3 py3-pip make g++
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY [ "package.json", "yarn.lock", "/usr/src/app/" ]
RUN yarn install --prod=true --frozen-lockfile
FROM node:lts-alpine3.16 
RUN apk add dumb-init
RUN mkdir -p /var/lib/sqlite
RUN chown node:node /var/lib/sqlite
USER node
WORKDIR /usr/app
COPY --chown=node:node --from=builder /usr/src/app/node_modules /usr/app/node_modules
COPY --chown=node:node . /usr/app/
CMD [ "dumb-init", "yarn", "start" ]
EXPOSE 5003
```

Here is the docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres
    hostname: ce-postgres
    container_name: ce-postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: *
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: *
      PGDATA: /var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 5434:5432
    volumes:
      - central-postgresql-volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  central-services:
    container_name: central-be-latest
    hostname: central-services
    entrypoint: >
      /bin/sh -c "
      npx sequelize-cli db:migrate;
      yarn start;
      "
    build:
      context: .
    environment:
      - DEV_DB_NAME=*
      - DEV_DB_USER=*
      - DEV_DB_PASS=*
      - DEV_DB_HOST=ce-*
      - NODE_ENV=development
      - AMQP_PRTO=* 
      - AMQP_SERVER=*
      - AMQP_PORT=*
      - AMQP_USER=*
      - AMQP_PWD=*
      - PORT=*
      - APP_HOST=*
      - APP_PORT=5003
      - DEV_AMQP_USER=*
      - DEV_AMQP_PASS=*
      - DEV_AMQP_HOST=*
      - DEV_AMQP_PORT=*
      - DEV_AMQP_PROTOCOL=*
      - DEV_AMQP_VHOST=*
      - REFUND_DIR=/var/lib/refunds/data
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    ports:
      - 8888:5003
    volumes:
      - refunds-volume:/var/lib/refunds/data
      - logs-volume:/var/lib/logs/data
      - ./:/app
      - /app/node_modules/
    networks:
      - rabbit-mq_rabbitmq_go_net
      - default

volumes:
  refunds-volume:
    external: true
  central-postgresql-volume:
    external: true
  logs-volume:
    external: true

networks:
  default:
    name: demo
  rabbit-mq_rabbitmq_go_net:
    external: true
```

Comment: What do the perimssions on that directory look like in the container, and what permissions does the user node have?

Comment: @neonwatty I don't know. how do I check those?

Comment: Check out a primer or two on permissions like [this one](https://www.guru99.com/file-permissions.html#:~:text=Linux%20divides%20the%20file%20permissions,ownership%20of%20a%20file%2Fdirectory) and [this one](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/uchmod.htm).